# In Unity Editor everything works fine, but in the build version it doesn't

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

help please, my code in Unity Editor is working perfectly fine, but in build everything is not working properly. Here are the errors I get in the built version of the game:

```
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in :0
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest…cctor () [0x00019] in :0
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for ‘System.Net.HttpWebRequest’ threw an exception.
at System.Net.Http.MonoWebRequestHandler…ctor () [0x00063] in <3f34347f51c3476589cbcd8e67ddd03e>:0
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.CreateDefaultHandler () [0x00000] in <3f34347f51c3476589cbcd8e67ddd03e>:0
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler…ctor () [0x00000] in <3f34347f51c3476589cbcd8e67ddd03e>:0
at RestSharp.RestClient+<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<.ctor>g__GetClient|0 () [0x00000] in <8477789b53584f06bdcef6bfc46931d4>:0
at RestSharp.RestClient…ctor (RestSharp.RestClientOptions options, RestSharp.ConfigureHeaders configureDefaultHeaders, RestSharp.ConfigureSerialization configureSerialization, System.Boolean useClientFactory) [0x00091] in <8477789b53584f06bdcef6bfc46931d4>:0
at RestSharp.RestClient…ctor (RestSharp.ConfigureRestClient configureRestClient, RestSharp.ConfigureHeaders configureDefaultHeaders, RestSharp.ConfigureSerialization configureSerialization, System.Boolean useClientFactory) [0x0000c] in <8477789b53584f06bdcef6bfc46931d4>:0
at ChatGPTAPI.GenerateDialogueWithoutDonation () [0x00052] in D:\TestProjectU\AI Podcast\Assets\ChatGPTAPI.cs:38
at Main.DialoguePreparationAfterStart () [0x0003e] in D:\TestProjectU\AI Podcast\Assets\Main.cs:37
at Main.MainManager (System.Boolean startMode) [0x00056] in D:\TestProjectU\AI Podcast\Assets\Main.cs:138
at Main.Start () [0x00047] in D:\TestProjectU\AI Podcast\Assets\Main.cs:32
at System.Net.Http.MonoWebRequestHandler…ctor () [0x00063] in <3f34347f51c3476589cbcd8e67ddd03e>:0
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.CreateDefaultHandler () [0x00000] in <3f34347f51c3476589cbcd8e67ddd03e>:0
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler…ctor () [0x00000] in <3f34347f51c3476589cbcd8e67ddd03e>:0
at RestSharp.RestClient+<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<.ctor>g__GetClient|0 () [0x00000] in <8477789b53584f06bdcef6bfc46931d4>:0
at RestSharp.RestClient…ctor (RestSharp.RestClientOptions options, RestSharp.ConfigureHeaders configureDefaultHeaders, RestSharp.ConfigureSerialization configureSerialization, System.Boolean useClientFactory) [0x00091] in <8477789b53584f06bdcef6bfc46931d4>:0
at RestSharp.RestClient…ctor (RestSharp.ConfigureRestClient configureRestClient, RestSharp.ConfigureHeaders configureDefaultHeaders, RestSharp.ConfigureSerialization configureSerialization, System.Boolean useClientFactory) [0x0000c] in <8477789b53584f06bdcef6bfc46931d4>:0
at DonationManager.RefreshToken () [0x0008d] in D:\TestProjectU\AI Podcast\Assets\DonationManager.cs:305
at DonationManager.Start () [0x00039] in D:\TestProjectU\AI Podcast\Assets\DonationManager.cs:30
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in :0
at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext+WorkRequest.Invoke () [0x00002] in C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Export\Scripting\UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:153
at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.Exec () [0x0005d] in C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Export\Scripting\UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:83
at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.ExecuteTasks () [0x00014] in C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Export\Scripting\UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:107
```

```
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in :0
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest…cctor () [0x00019] in :0
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for ‘System.Net.HttpWebRequest’ threw an exception.
at System.Net.Http.MonoWebRequestHandler…ctor () [0x00063] in <3f34347f51c3476589cbcd8e67ddd03e>:0
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.CreateDefaultHandler () [0x00000] in <3f34347f51c3476589cbcd8e67ddd03e>:0
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler…ctor () [0x00000] in <3f34347f51c3476589cbcd8e67ddd03e>:0
at RestSharp.RestClient+<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<.ctor>g__GetClient|0 () [0x00000] in <8477789b53584f06bdcef6bfc46931d4>:0
at RestSharp.RestClient…ctor (RestSharp.RestClientOptions options, RestSharp.ConfigureHeaders configureDefaultHeaders, RestSharp.ConfigureSerialization configureSerialization, System.Boolean useClientFactory) [0x00091] in <8477789b53584f06bdcef6bfc46931d4>:0
at RestSharp.RestClient…ctor (RestSharp.ConfigureRestClient configureRestClient, RestSharp.ConfigureHeaders configureDefaultHeaders, RestSharp.ConfigureSerialization configureSerialization, System.Boolean useClientFactory) [0x0000c] in <8477789b53584f06bdcef6bfc46931d4>:0
at ChatGPTAPI.GenerateDialogueWithoutDonation () [0x00052] in D:\TestProjectU\AI Podcast\Assets\ChatGPTAPI.cs:38
at Main.DialoguePreparationAfterStart () [0x0003e] in D:\TestProjectU\AI Podcast\Assets\Main.cs:37
at Main.MainManager (System.Boolean startMode) [0x00056] in D:\TestProjectU\AI Podcast\Assets\Main.cs:138
at Main.Start () [0x00047] in D:\TestProjectU\AI Podcast\Assets\Main.cs:32
at System.Net.Http.MonoWebRequestHandler…ctor () [0x00063] in <3f34347f51c3476589cbcd8e67ddd03e>:0
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.CreateDefaultHandler () [0x00000] in <3f34347f51c3476589cbcd8e67ddd03e>:0
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler…ctor () [0x00000] in <3f34347f51c3476589cbcd8e67ddd03e>:0
at RestSharp.RestClient+<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<.ctor>g__GetClient|0 () [0x00000] in <8477789b53584f06bdcef6bfc46931d4>:0
at RestSharp.RestClient…ctor (RestSharp.RestClientOptions options, RestSharp.ConfigureHeaders configureDefaultHeaders, RestSharp.ConfigureSerialization configureSerialization, System.Boolean useClientFactory) [0x00091] in <8477789b53584f06bdcef6bfc46931d4>:0
at RestSharp.RestClient…ctor (RestSharp.ConfigureRestClient configureRestClient, RestSharp.ConfigureHeaders configureDefaultHeaders, RestSharp.ConfigureSerialization configureSerialization, System.Boolean useClientFactory) [0x0000c] in <8477789b53584f06bdcef6bfc46931d4>:0
at DonationManager.RefreshToken () [0x0008d] in D:\TestProjectU\AI Podcast\Assets\DonationManager.cs:305
at DonationManager.Start () [0x00039] in D:\TestProjectU\AI Podcast\Assets\DonationManager.cs:30
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in :0
at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext+WorkRequest.Invoke () [0x00002] in C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Export\Scripting\UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:153
at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.Exec () [0x0005d] in C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Export\Scripting\UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:83
at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.ExecuteTasks () [0x00014] in C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Export\Scripting\UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:107
```

I created a build of the game expecting everything to work the same as in the Unity Editor, but as a result nothing works. I use Newtonsoft libraries.Json, RestSharp and Sqlite in my project. Maybe it's because of libraries?

Comment: Are you using IL2CPP or Mono?

Comment: Hello, using Mono

Comment: it reads like something was web downloaded and failed to download it..

Comment: To me, it looks like the ConfigurationManager is somehow not initialized in your build. Can you share your build settings? Since you are using Mono, we can rule out that IL2CPP apparently doesn't support it: https://forum.unity.com/threads/system-configuration-configurationmanager-on-il2cpp-is-possible.1182706/

Comment: Tried changing Mono to IL2CPPP now and everything worked.

Comment: Could you also please tell me if there is any way to make a console in the build on IL2CPPPP? On Mono I could just switch on Development Build and the console was there.

Comment: Unity helps to make unified code for different platforms. However, it does not guarantee that all the code that works in the editor will work on other platforms. It can be related to many reasons, including one really important - unity c# is not the same as .net c#.